# how to generate documentation of jfreechart using ant

Tags: java, ant

I am using jfreechart in my project. No documentation is provided.  However a build.xml is provided which can generate documentation.
I have downloaded ant 1.8.2 and installed in c:\ant\ant 1.8.2. from CMD prompt, when i type ant javadoc, i get the error saying:
 Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\li
b\tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

I have pasted my build.xml file into c:\ant\ant 1.8.2.
Just to tell you all, i have jre 6 in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6. 
I have also set environment variable path to  c:\ant\ant 1.8.2\bin.
Where am i doing it wrong? can it be done?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I solved tools.jar problem. Simply pasted tools.jar from jdk 6 folder to jre/lib folder.

Comment: I did C:\ant.1.7.1\apache-ant-1.8.2>ant javadoc -d G:\Project material\jfreechart-1.0.
13\ant. The g:\ folder is where my jfreechart is present. I get the error C:\ant.1.7.1\apache-ant-1.8.2\build.xml:151: C:\ant.1.7.1\source does not exist.

Comment: FYI - The the warning about tools.jar is because you are running ANT with the JRE, not the JDK.  It isn't always required, but most often people running ANT are compiling Java files, which would require the JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ensure that you are in the directory that contains the build.xml file when you run `ant javadoc`**.

Rather than putting the build.xml file into your ANT install directories, [install it by seting up your environment so that you can run ANT from anywhere](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html).  Then, CD to the directory that contains the build.xml and execute `ant javadoc`.

When you execute ANT, [it expects to find a build.xml file in the directory that you are executing from, unless you specify a buildfile using the -buildfile option.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)

> To make Ant use a build file other
>   than build.xml, use the command-line
>   option -buildfile file, where file is
>   the name of the build file you want to
>   use.

The warning about tools.jar is because you are running with the JRE, rather than a JDK.  If you aren't compiling Java files, then you probably don't have to worry about it.  ANT will run the majority of the tasks just fine using the JRE.

Comment: Thanks mads. It worked. I was just trying out too many things.